# how do you select an item from a listview and use it in say, a label or text using Basic4android

Tags: basic4android

i want to scroll to an item in a listview and select that item to use in a label or text etc
How do you code to select an item from a list say using a 'long click' or similar to highlight it??
I have found many responses to this question but I cannot see one that specifically shows this using Basic4android.
Can't help being old and stupid I guess but a thing like this shouldn't really be this hard or generate so many how too's?
Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [ListView Tutorial](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/6537-listview-tutorial.html#post38231)? I believe that the first example should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks Erel. I missed that completely before for some reason.                   now I use Sub ListView1_ItemClick (Position As Int, Value As Object)
              aetext1.text= Value

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Process_Globals
    Type twostrings (aLabel As String , bLabel As String)
        Dim oGPS As GPS
End Sub

sub LoadList
            Dim ts As twostrings
            ts.Initialize
            ts.aLabel="ABC"
            ts.bLabel="ABC Description"
            listMyData.AddTwoLines2(ts.aLabel,ts.bLabel,ts)
end sub
sub listMyData_Click(Position as Int, Value as Object)
    Dim ts As twostrings
    ts.Initialize
    ts=Value
    lblLabelA.Text=ts.aLabel
    lblLabelB.Text=ts.bLabel
end sub
```